# Eclipse JBoss Plugin Wildfly 28 Support

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, wildfly

I am using Eclipse version 2022-06 with JBoss Tools 4.24.0.Final plugin installed.

With this setup,  I have been able to configure Wilfly 10 server on Eclipse.

Now we are moving to Wildfly 28. The latest available Wildfly version supported by the JBoss plugin in Eclipse is "Wildfly 24+".

Does the "Wildfly 24+" version mean that this will also support Wildfly 28" too.

Whilst it does suggest this. just wanted some conformation please.

Thank you

Comment: Considering that there's an Eclipse 202**3**-06 and JBoss Tools 4.2**8**.0.Final download, why are you using backlevel versions?

Comment: I am constrained by the fact that I am only able to go up to Java 11.
From https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation, the latest Eclipse version that would run with Java 11 is Eclipse 4.24 (2022-06).
From https://tools.jboss.org/downloads/archives.html, using Eclipse 4.24 (2022-06)., the latest version of JBoss tools that i can use is 4.24.0.Final. What I am not able to determine what versions of Wildfly are supported by Jboss tools 4.24.0.Final.  How can i check this please ?

Comment: The version of Java you use to run Eclipse has little bearing on the version of Java you use to compile and run your own code and app servers. I have no idea what versions of the JBoss Tools support which Wildfly versions, but I would guess that the similarities in version numbering aren't a coincidence.

Comment: Hello @nitind. Thank you for the clarification. So completely wrong understanding on my side. I thought the Eclipse version I used had to be the same Java version as the Java version used in the target environment of the compiled code.  I have done what you suggest before to use "Eclipse 2023-06 and JBoss Tools 4.28.0.Final". The latest supported Wildfly is "Wildfly 27+". This much better than "Wildfly 24+" I was getting with "Eclipse version 2022-06" and "JBoss Tools 4.24.0.Final" plugin. I am assumed "Wildfly 27+" will support "Wildfly28" (figers crossed). Finally Thank you nitind